# bind and boost function

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I'm trying to make a map with boost::bind like this :

```cpp
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::assign;

class BaseClass{
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base" << std::endl;}
};

class childClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "derived" << std::endl;}
    ~childClass () {
        std::cout << "childClass destructor" << std::endl;   
    }
};

int main()
{

    boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> pBase;
    // need help to make this bind work
    boost::bind( static_cast<void( boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>::* )()>( &boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>::reset ), pBase,
                  boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>(new childClass() ) ) ;



    return 0;
}
```

I got this error :

> C2825   'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
>
> C2510   'F': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
>
> C3646   'type': unknown override specifier
>
> C4430    missing type specifier
>
> C2039   'type': is not a member of 'boost::_bi::result_traits'

It seems like the bind is not correct.

Comment: Shared pointer to class method? This is the problem and this is pointless. `shared_ptr` is good for resources with finitive lifetime. Every function/method in C++ is eternal and do not need cleanup (there is case of managing dll-s, but this is different topic not related to your issue).

Comment: To show you what you should do, show us: Code which you wish to bind and how you want to use this binding. It would be best if you provide [mcve]. You can use this site: https://wandbox.org/ .

Comment: here is a example of how I want to use the bind : [Link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e040e5356f6b049)

Comment: Are you forced to use C++03? Your code suggest that.

Comment: The code I'm working on is developped like this...

Comment: After your last edit it is pretty clear for me this is classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are asking how to fix your X solution for Y, instead asking how to do Y.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in comment you made it over-complicated and you where adding shared pointer in place where it is not needed.

```
Map_t g_cmdMap;
g_cmdMap["cmd"] = boost::bind(&BaseClass::foo, boost::make_shared<BaseClass>());
g_cmdMap["alt"] = boost::bind(&BaseClass::foo, boost::make_shared<childClass>());
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2728e997946d1f2e

Comment: I need to bind the reset function of shared_ptr to a object BaseClass using the argument "new childBase" Do you think it's possible ?
(i.e. cBaseClass.reset( new ChildBase1 );)

Comment: You misunderstand what `boost::bind` and `boost::function` do. Explain functionality you want to achieve since it is impossible to understood it from your code. I suspecting that removing item from `map` is thing you need.

Comment: I need to create a map that for each string reset an object with a new argument. What I understood from your explanation it's not a boost function that I need for that to work ? If this is the case a map of strings and object would correct ? and how to fix the bind ?

Comment: This is not functionality description, but description how you want to do something. Classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'll edit my code to focus on my problem. The fonctionnality of the map is to provide a object for each string

Comment: Thanks for your support every body.
for those how are looking for an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217660/using-boost-function-with-boost-bind-with-a-map

Comment: Ok you've got an answer which made it compiling, but I'm still convinced that it doesn't do what you relay need. Note you can't invoke this bind multiple times since later cleanup will end with a crash.

Comment: In fact it's part of the solution I'm looking for. After discution It's gonna be called only once but I'm intersted in an explaation in why it's gonna en with a crash during cleanup ?

Comment: forget about it. My moment of weakness ;).