# Using boost function with boost bind with a map

Tags: c++, boost, bind

In this code, the line `(iter->second)();` calls the function `reset(new childClass())`. Is this correct ? 
If this is the case, it is called on which object ?

```cpp
class BaseClass{
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base" << std::endl;}
};

class childClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "derived" << std::endl;}
    ~childClass () {
        std::cout << "childClass destructor" << std::endl;   
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, boost::function<void()>> Map_t;

    Map_t g_cmdMap = map_list_of( "cmd",
                boost::bind( static_cast<void( boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>::* )()>( &boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>::reset ), 
                  boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>(new childClass() ) )) ;

    std::map<std::string, boost::function<void()>>::iterator iter;
    iter = g_cmdMap.find( "cmd" );
    (iter->second)();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the `line (iter->second)();` calls the function `reset(new childClass())`. Is this correct?

No, it invokes `reset()`. If you want it to be called as `reset(new childClass())`, you need to pass `new childClass()` to `boost::bind` as argument like

```
boost::bind( static_cast<void( boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>::* )(BaseClass*)>( 
               &boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>::reset ), 
             boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>(new childClass() ),
             new childClass() )
```

Note that `new childClass()` itself is evaluated when `boost::bind` is invoked, not the functor is invoked.

Or you can add a placeholder, and pass `new childClass()` when call the functor.

> it is called on which object ?

It's called on the object copied from the argument passed to `boost::bind`, i.e. `boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>(new childClass() )`.

Comment: Even then it would not be equivalent to `reset(new childClass());` rather it would be equivalent to `reset(tmObj);` where `tmpObj` is `childClass` object created when `bind()` was called.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the tmpobj ? If this is the case how can we do that ?
And is it possible to call reset on an exisiting object and not a tmpobj ?
Thanks All for you support.

Comment: It's possible by doing someting like this :


`boost::bind( static_cast<void( boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>::* )(BaseClass*)>( &boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass>::reset ), &pBaseClass, new childClass() );`